# execute-command; limit program cpu usage for executable program

Tags: execute-command

Is it possible to limit usage of a program to specific kernel or limit usage of processor capacity?

It otherwise runs on 100% during long time.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man bash`, and look for the `ulimit` section that starts with:

```
   ulimit [-HSTabcdefilmnpqrstuvx [limit]]
          Provides  control over the resources available to the shell and to processes started by it, on systems that allow such control.
```

Also read `man nice`:

```
NAME
   nice - run a program with modified scheduling priority
```